# How do I use python's typing module?

Tags: python, types

I'm trying to run OCRmypdf using their python API. I can run it when I do not declare a language. When I try to declare a language, however, it throws an error. The api.py file uses typing to declare `language: List[str] = None` so I imported List from typing and tried to declare a lang variable, this threw an error.

My code:

```
source = 'fr'; target = 'en'; tess_lang = 'fr'
x: List[str] = ['eng', 'fr']
for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    print(files)
    for pdf in [file for file in files if '.pdf' in file.lower()]:
        ocrmypdf.ocr(language = x, input_file = pdf, output_file = pdf.rsplit('.', 1)[0]+'_new.pdf', rotate_pages=True, deskew=True, force_ocr = True)
```

The error:

```
<ipython-input-41-90f7f46b6092> in <module>
      5     print(files)
      6     for pdf in [file for file in files if '.pdf' in file.lower()]:
----> 7         ocrmypdf.ocr(language = x, input_file = pdf, output_file = pdf.rsplit('.', 1)[0]+'_new.pdf', rotate_pages=True, deskew=True, force_ocr = True)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ocrmypdf\api.py in ocr(input_file, output_file, language, image_dpi, output_type, sidecar, jobs, use_threads, title, author, subject, keywords, rotate_pages, remove_background, deskew, clean, clean_final, unpaper_args, oversample, remove_vectors, threshold, force_ocr, skip_text, redo_ocr, skip_big, optimize, jpg_quality, png_quality, jbig2_lossy, jbig2_page_group_size, pages, max_image_mpixels, tesseract_config, tesseract_pagesegmode, tesseract_oem, pdf_renderer, tesseract_timeout, rotate_pages_threshold, pdfa_image_compression, user_words, user_patterns, fast_web_view, keep_temporary_files, progress_bar, tesseract_env)
    248     """
    249 
--> 250     options = create_options(**locals())
    251     check_options(options)
    252     return run_pipeline(options, api=True)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ocrmypdf\api.py in create_options(input_file, output_file, **kwargs)
    149             cmdline.append(str(val))
    150         else:
--> 151             raise TypeError(f"{arg}: {val} ({type(val)})")
    152 
    153     cmdline.append(str(input_file))

TypeError: language: ['eng', 'fr'] (<class 'list'>)
```

Comment: You error seems to have nothing to do with typing, as far as I can tell.

Comment: this appears to be a mistake in their type annotation, afaict it should be `Optional[str]` and not `List[str]`

Comment: As an aside, `language: List[str] = None` is incorrectly typed ... they are saying that the variable must be a list of strings but then assign `None` to it... Any type checker would fail this immediately (and, I would say, any moderately competent programmer would spot the error immediately)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in their type annotation, it should probably be `language: Optional[str] = None`

to pass multiple languages, it appears you can use [`language='eng+fr'`](https://ocrmypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/languages.html#debian-and-ubuntu-users)

the way their "api" works is they box up all of those arguments and then [feed them through their commandline parser](https://github.com/jbarlow83/OCRmyPDF/blob/054c0773a3c8ec6fe0bab6dc586d4f0217263e57/src/ocrmypdf/api.py#L124-L151) -- this only has support for scalar values (no `List`s, etc.)